# Modular Forms: With special congruences!

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, fourier-transform, modular-forms, arithmetic-functions

Remember the Fourier expansion of the full modular form:
$$ \Delta(z) = \sum_{n=1} \tau(n)q^n $$
where $\tau(n)$ are the coefficients (Ramanujan Tau function). Ramanujan found that the coefficients satisfy
$$ \tau(n) \equiv \sigma_{11}(n) \mod 691 $$
where $\sigma_{11}(n) = \sum_{d|n}d^{11}$. 
My question:

> Do you know other modular forms which Fourier expansion coefficients satisfy *such* a congruence?

With *such* I mean this: Let $f(z)$ be a modular form so that $f(z)=\sum a_nq^n$. Now I want to find a congruence such as $$ a_n \equiv g(n) \mod m $$
where $g(n)$ is a (simple) arithmetic function such as the divisor sum function $\sigma(n)$ and $m$ favorable a prime.

Comment: These things are pretty common. What's really going on here is that $\Delta$ is congruent to the Eisenstein series $E_{12}$ modulo $691$. If $f$ is any modular eigenform, and $\rho_l:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb Q}_l)$ is its associated $l$-adic Galois representation, then a congruence of this type will exist whenever $\rho_l$ is reducible modulo $l$. Whilst for any given $f$, this can only happen for finitely many primes, it's pretty common that it will happen for at least one.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example?

Comment: [Kilford](https://www.google.fr/search?q="Kilford+L.+Modular+forms..+A+classical+and+computational+introduction+(ICP%2C+2008)(ISBN+1848162138)(237s)_MT.pdf")'s book has a chapter about modular forms $\bmod p$.

Answer (score 0):

One example is $f(z)=\eta(3\tau)^9/\eta(\tau)^3= q + 3q^2 + 9q^3 + 13q^4 + 24q^5 + 27q^6 + \dots\;$ where $a_n=g(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^2\;\big($ $\!\!n/d\over{3}$ $\!\!\big)\;$ and $\;(\;.\mid 3)$ is a Kronecker symbol. Now $a_n \equiv g(n) \pmod m$ for any integer $m$. See OEIS sequence [A106402](http://oeis.org/A106402) for more details of this modular form.

Other examples are in this [Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59192/) about sequences [A001935](http://oeis.org/A001935) and [A001936](http://oeis.org/A001936). $\sigma(8n+1) \equiv A001935(n) \pmod 4$ and $\sigma(4n+1) \equiv A001936(n) \pmod 4.$

Related example $f(z)=\eta(4\tau)^8/\eta(2\tau)^4=q +4q^3 +6q^5 +8q^7 +13q^9 +12q^{11}+\dots\;$ where $a_n=\sigma(n)\;$ for all odd $n$. Another exmaple is this [Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230737/) about
sequence [A145722](http://oeis.org/A145722) where $\;\sigma(4n-3) \equiv A145722(n-1) \pmod 5.$

Comment: And what is this congruent to?

Comment: How is $F(s) = \zeta(s-2) L(s,\chi_3)$ is the L-series of a modular form ? Ah I got it : it is because $F(3-s)$ is (up to some gamma factors) again a Dirichlet series.