# Why is the calculation of Fourier coefficients of Klein's modular function important?

Tags: fourier-series, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

For $n \geq 3$, the series
$$
G_n = \sum_{\omega \neq 0} \frac{1}{\omega^n}
$$
is the Eisenstein series of order $n$. Let $g_2 = 60G_4$ and $g_3=140G_6$. Then, the number $\Delta = g_2^3 - 27g_3^2$ is called the discriminant.

For given periods $\omega_1, \omega_2$ with $\omega_2 / \omega_1 \notin \mathbb{R}$, we define
$$
J(\omega_1, \omega_2) = \frac{g_2^3(\omega_1, \omega_2)}{\Delta(\omega_1, \omega_2)},
$$
which is called Klein's modular function. For any $\tau \in \mathcal{H}$, we know that $J(\tau)$ is analytic in $\mathcal{H}$. We also have the Fourier expansion
$$
12^3J(\tau) = e^{-2\pi i \tau} + 744 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c(n)e^{2\pi i n \tau},
$$
where the $c(n)$ are integers.

In the literature, many studies have been done on the calculation of these coefficients $c(n)$.

**My Question: Why is the calculation of these coefficients important? Is knowing these coefficients related to solving more concrete problems in different areas such as number theory?**

Comment: Which study in particular?

Comment: According to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KleinsAbsoluteInvariant.html "The function $J(\tau)$ is the same as the j-function, modulo a constant multiplicative factor", and according to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html Hermite used the j-function in solving the quintic in about 1858, and the j-function is related to the factors of the group order of the monster group and to supersingular primes.

Comment: In [Monstrous moonshine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine) the integer $\,c(1)=196884\,$ is one more than the dimension of the smallest irreducible complex representation of the Monster finite simple group.

Answer (score 1):

The comment above by Michael Somos points out that the coefficient $196884$ at $n = 1$ is nearly equal to $196883$, which is the smallest nontrivial irreducible representation of the Monster group:
$$
c(1) = 196884 = 1 + 196883.
$$
The trivial representation has dimension $1$, so the above equation expresses $c(1)$ as a sum of the smallest two dimensions of irreducible representations  of the Monster. And the higher coefficients of the $j$-function are linear combinations of dimensions of irreducible representations of the Monster with "small" coefficients. This is called monstrous moonshine, and proving it is part of what earned Borcherds the Fields medal. It is an unexpected connection between a function from  complex analysis and pure algebra.

There is a chapter on congruence properties of the $j$-function in Apostol's *Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory*, but maybe that doesn't interest you. Nevertheless, congruence properties of coefficients in $q$-expansions of modular forms (the $j$-function is not a modular form, but it shares some properties with them) do interest people, since it reflects properties of Galois representations. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446174/modular-forms-with-special-congruences).